# How to divide the SQL single column for multiple use

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My Database Table values are inserted like below.

```
 Userid       AttedanceDate             SessionType 

 mazhar    2016-01-02 10:37:22.397         login

 mazhar    2016-01-03 10:38:24.970         logout

 mazhar    2016-01-02 11:39:22.397         login

 mazhar     2016-01-02 11:40:24.970        logout

 mazhar    2016-01-03 10:37:22.397         login

 mazhar     2016-01-03 10:38:24.970        logout
```

I need result like below.

```
Userid       AttedanceDatelogin         AttedanceDatelogout        Total Hours   

 mazhar        2016-01-02 10:37:22.397    2016-01-02 11:40:24.970      01:02
 mazhar        2016-01-03 10:37:22.397    2016-01-03 10:38:24.970      00:01
```

My select query.

```
select  t1.AttendanceDate,t1.Userid,t1.SessionType from Table_Branches_AttendanceInfo as t1 inner join Table_Authorize_Users as t2 on t1.Userid=t2.Userid where (CONVERT(varchar(50), AttendanceDate, 101) BETWEEN @Fromdate AND @Todate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT UserId, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'login' THEN AttedanceDate END) AS AttedanceDatelogin,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'logout' THEN AttedanceDate END) AS AttedanceDatelogout,
       DATEDIFF(hour, 
                MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'login' THEN AttedanceDate END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'logout' THEN AttedanceDate END)) AS TotalHours
FROM Table_Branches_AttendanceInfo as t
GROUP BY Userid
```

**Edit**:

For multiple logins / logouts per day you can use the following query that considers only the first login and last logout of each day:

```
SELECT UserId, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'login' THEN AttedanceDate END) AS AttedanceDatelogin,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'logout' THEN AttedanceDate END) AS AttedanceDatelogout,
       DATEDIFF(hour, 
                MIN(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'login' THEN AttedanceDate END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'logout' THEN AttedanceDate END)) AS TotalHours
FROM Table_Branches_AttendanceInfo as t
GROUP BY Userid, CONVERT(DATE, AttedanceDate)
```

**Edit2:**

To get hours / minutes you can use:

```
SELECT UserId, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'login' THEN AttedanceDate END) AS AttedanceDatelogin,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'logout' THEN AttedanceDate END) AS AttedanceDatelogout,
       DATEDIFF(hour, 
                MIN(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'login' THEN AttedanceDate END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'logout' THEN AttedanceDate END)) AS Hours,
       DATEDIFF(minute, 
                MIN(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'login' THEN AttedanceDate END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN SessionType = 'logout' THEN AttedanceDate END)) % 60 AS Minutes
FROM mytable as t
GROUP BY Userid, CONVERT(DATE, AttedanceDate)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04e52/9)

Comment: if record save login 6 times and logout 6 times in same day, then result is showing in negative values. I need result per days, not all days in one query. @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: @zahed Can you show some sample data along with required result set demonstrating this case?

Comment: Please check once i updated my question, you will understand. @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: @zahed What if a user logs in late at night and then logs out early in the morning of the *following* day?

Comment: No, if they will go for lunch and tea break, then will do login and logout in same day, can do group by first login and logout, and then second login and logout like that. @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: One more idea we can do, day first login and day last logout, then we can count hours and order by per day record show not with all. @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: Please check once again i had updated my question, day first login and day last logout then count hours. @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: @zahed Check the edit I made. You will have to fiddle with `DATEDIFF` in order to get correct difference in hours/minutes.

Comment: I am not getting minutes, only hours is showing, can update that also because new in SQL. @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: Please tell me if you know that also other wise I will update your answer. @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: Thank you very much. @Giorgos Betsos

Answer (score 1):

In *SQL Server* you can achieve It in following:

**QUERY**

```
 select userid
        , max(case when SessionType = 'login' then AttedanceDate end) as AttedanceDatelogin          
        , max(case when SessionType = 'logout' then AttedanceDate end) as AttedanceDatelogout  
        , datediff(hh, max(case when SessionType = 'login' then AttedanceDate end), max(case when SessionType = 'logout' then AttedanceDate end)) Hours  
 from #t
 group by UserId
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table #t
(
   Userid nvarchar(60),       
   AttedanceDate datetime,
   SessionType  nvarchar(60)
)
insert into #t values 
   ('mazhar','2016-01-02 10:37:22.397','login'),
   ('mazhar','2016-01-03 10:38:24.970','logout'),
   ('mazhar','2016-01-02 11:39:22.397','login'),
   ('mazhar','2016-01-02 11:40:24.970','logout'),
   ('mazhar','2016-01-03 10:37:22.397','login'),
   ('mazhar','2016-01-03 10:38:24.970','logout')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
userid  AttedanceDatelogin      AttedanceDatelogout         Hours
mazhar  2016-01-02 10:37:22.397 2016-01-02 11:37:24.970     1
```

---

**EDIT #1**

As per your comment to achieve that you can in following:

```
 select userid
        , min(case when SessionType = 'login' then AttedanceDate end) as AttedanceDatelogin          
        , max(case when SessionType = 'logout' then AttedanceDate end) as AttedanceDatelogout  
        , convert(char(5),dateadd(ss,datediff(ss, min(case when SessionType = 'login' then AttedanceDate end), max(case when SessionType = 'logout' then AttedanceDate end)),'19000101'),8) Hours  
 from #t
 group by UserId, convert(date, AttedanceDate)
```

**OUTPUT AFTER EDIT**

```
userid  AttedanceDatelogin          AttedanceDatelogout         Hours
mazhar  2016-01-02 10:37:22.397     2016-01-02 11:40:24.970     01:03
mazhar  2016-01-03 10:37:22.397     2016-01-03 10:38:24.970     00:01
```

Comment: if record save login 6 times and logout 6 times in same day, then result is showing in negative values. I need result per days, not all days in one query. @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas

Comment: Thank you very much. @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select userid
        , min(case when SessionType = 'login' then AttedanceDate end) as AttedanceDatelogin          
        , max(case when SessionType = 'logout' then AttedanceDate end) as AttedanceDatelogout  
        ,CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, min(case when SessionType = 'login' then AttedanceDate end), max(case when SessionType = 'logout' then AttedanceDate end)), 0), 114) as TotalHours
 from TableDemo
 group by UserId,CONVERT(date,AttedanceDate)
```